# Does snowflake database provide design time artifacts than runtime artifacts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When i mean runtime artifacts(it means running a sql query to create a table and its lost) views the same.
Design time means writing scripts that contains code which generates the runtime objects like table view and procedure creation.
I am new to Snowflake please let me know.

Comment: Snowflake does not provide any "design tools", I almost guess by your definitions the WebUI might be considered a "run time artifact", but in general if what you mean is point and click UI like MS products might have, then no. 
You write sql (or use an external tool) to write sql, and you run sql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create objects like tables in Snowflake "on the fly" with SQL. So if you log into the WebUI or via SnowSQL (command line tool) you can issue the following sorts of statements to create a new table:

```
create table mytable (amount number);
```

You can also write such statements in files and execute those scripts later on. Both options are available - and you can also dynamically generate sql in the javascript stored procedures. There are a bunch of options available to you - but it's mostly done via plain SQL. Have a look here for creating tables syntax:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html

Is there any specific use case you have in mind?